# Text flow up into the table in Mobi file

Tags: conversion, mobi, kindlegen

I have created `.ePub` from *Indesign*, perfected the layout to match that of the `.PDF` and converted to `.MOBI` using *KindleGen*. The text/image appearing after some of the tables flow into the table. Only some have problems. *DIV* marker is added at the end of the table.

How can I keep the table intact and ensure that Text/Image will have some vertical space below the table? Using *Kindle Previewer* and *Kindle Paperwhite 3G* to read the `.Mobi` file.